# An error occurred while running ionic cordova build android

Tags: ionic4

when build android app using ionic ionic cordova build android comment getting an error

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information
```

ionic cordova build android

ionic cordova build android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

> As of Cordova-Android 6.4.0, [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/) is now required to be installed to build Android.
>
> When installing on Windows, you need to add Gradle to your path, (see
>   [Setting Environment Variables](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#setting-environment-variables))